# ¿Cómo actualizar un registro sin que me dé error de nombre repetido? Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy intentando hacer el formulario de actualizar Areas en Laravel 5.6.

He leído información y he visto varios ejemplos pero ninguna me ha funcionado, siempre me da error de que el nombre y la etiqueta ya existen.

Mi código del controlador es:

```
public function update(Request $request, Area $area)
    {
         $fields = request()->validate([
            'name' => 'required|unique:areas|max:60|min:2,'.$area->id,
            'tag' =>  'required|unique:areas|max:500,'.$area->id,
            'plant_id' =>  'exists:plants,id'
        ]);
        $area->update($fields);
        return redirect()->route('areas.index')->with('status', 'Area updated!');
    }
```

Fuentes:

[Forcing a unique rule to ignore a given id](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/forcing-a-unique-rule-to-ignore-a-given-id)

[How to use the ignore rule in Form Request Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47646900/laravel-how-to-use-the-ignore-rule-in-form-request-validation)

Comment: Pues tu mismo le estás diciendo en la regla `unique:areas` que quieres que la columna `name` de tu tabla `areas` no se repitan sus valores, al igual que el campo `tag`, no entiendo cual es la duda. Normalmente se usa esa regla para evitar errores de base de datos cuando tienes un índice único en algún campo.

Comment: Claro, "name" y "tag" deben ser únicos con respecto a otros registros, pero al editar un área yo decido si cambiarlos o no. Dicho de otra forma, deben ser únicos pero con una excepción (ignorando el actual ID).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tu controlador tendría que quedar algo así

```
public function update(Request $request, Area $area)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:60|min:2|unique:areas,name,'.$area->id,
        'tag' =>  'required|max:500|unique:areas,tag,'.$area->id,
        'plant_id' =>  'exists:plants,id'
    ]);
    $area->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('areas.index')->with('status', 'Area updated!');
}
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado!! muchas gracias.